# How do you remove all content within an element including the javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm using ajax to get the content (html, css, javascript) from another file. Everything works perfected initially; however, if I run this ajax request a second time, all the javascript from the first call remains saved on the dom, so any `.on("click")` functions get executed twice. I've tried `$("#contentHolder").empty()` with no success. Also, I do need to execute the ajax call more than once (I can't call it once, save the content, then just `.hide/.show` as needed).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "page.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        $("#contentHolder").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Before every ```.on("click",function(){....})``` function, add ```.off("click")``` to unbind the event and element.

Comment: Uhm, guys, what presumptions are being made here? We have no `on` or `off` code to go from, just a random ajax request? This question needs more clarification if anything, not just a random stab in the dark that "works"...

Comment: @somethinghere .. not a presumption. OP mentioned, ```on("click")``` is firing multiple times which tells me that the ajax request has some javascript code with click events for element/elements contained in the response. I don't know if we need to review the coding practices here. @James , @somethinghere is correct though. It'd make sense to share what you receive in ```data``` to get a proper answer.